# Set Nginx redirect rule priority

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I have nginx+php-fpm and some rewrite rules for sef-urls.

The problem is that all my custom redirects/rewrites are ignored and request going to php script instead redirecting.

Part for sef-links:

```
if ($request_filename !~ ".(png|gif|ico|swf|jpe?g|js|css)$"){
        set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}   
if (!-f $request_filename){
        set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
}   
if (!-d $request_filename){
        set $rule_0 3$rule_0;
}   
if ($rule_0 = "321"){
        rewrite /. /index.php?sef_rewrite=1 last;
}
```

And I want to do that redirect:

```
location = /first.html {
    return 301 /second.html;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to thing in terms of nginx's locations and rules. Then it will be much easier to write proper config. Try this one:

```
location / {
    # replacement for last three `if`s
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?sef_rewrite=1;
}

# here is you redirect
location = /first.html {
    return 301 /second.html;
}

# this is replacement for first `if`
location ~ \.(png|gif|ico|swf|jpe?g|js|css)$ {
    # serve static files
}

# I'm sure you have this block somewhere
location ~ \.php$ {
    # serve php
}
```

Also these articles worth to read them:

- http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
- http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

Comment: Thanks.
Now I see the "true" way. But I've a new "surprise", all my ajax requests are failed. I think they are just being rewritten by /index.php?sef_rewrite=1

Comment: Well, I can't guess what are your ajax request and how they failed. Show full nginx config and what exactly failed